# LateX - Font issue with OT1pcr.fd file

Tags: fonts, texmaker

I'm trying to compile a tex file using TexMaker but I got the following error

> LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OT1+pcr on input line 220.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1pcr.fd
>   File: OT1pcr.fd 1995/12/14 Fontinst v1.500 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
>   )
>
> ! Font OT1/pcr/m/n/12=pcrr7t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

I understand that some packages are missing, I've tried to install the latest version of TexMaker from the website but it didn't solve the problem. I've also tried to edit the OT1pcr.fd file according to this [link](http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/psnfss.extra/OT1pcr.fd) with no success.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The document is too long and I'm not able to identify the lines causing the problem. Thank you anyway

Comment: Note that you could *definitely* have produced a small MWE to demonstrate this problem. Please read the instructions @JuriRobl linked to to familiarise yourself with the procedure. (It is easier to learn when you are not trying to solve an immediate problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved installing the texlive-fonts-recommended package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```