# XeLaTex and TexMaker "cannot-use-pdftex"

Tags: xetex, luatex

I would like to use the CV template provided by this [link](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv).

In the .tex file the author recommends to compile with XeLaTeX. In TeXmaker 4.0, I've used the right option to compile but the following error showed up:

> ! Fatal fontspec
>   error: "cannot-use-pdftex"

Should I try to compile using the LuaLaTeX support?

**EDIT**
The texlive-xetex package was not installed on the system

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

-> Now I can compile. Another error came out:

> File `layaureo.sty' not found

**EDIT 2**
I installed texlive-lang-italian package

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-italian
```

Now the error is:

> ! Font \XeTeXLink@font=pzdr at 0.00002pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or ins

Solved using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

from my old [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163817/latex-font-issue-with-ot1pcr-fd-file)

Comment: Then you are not using XeLaTeX. May be add `%!TEX TS-program = xelatex` as the first line of the document.

Comment: I've added it to the first line. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood TeXWorks, I don't know if TeXMaker follows those directives. Are you sure you told the program to call XeLaTeX? Because for what you say, it seems that it's calling pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Yes it was correctly set up. The texlive-xetex package was not installed! That's weird, it should have been marked as a dependency for the texmaker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package required to compile using XeLaTeX was not installed on my linux ditribution. Solved with:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

Answer (score 2):

If you compile with XeLaTeX and have the `Fontin` fonts installed on your system it works fine after some modifications to the preamble and the very beginning  of the file.

The main modifications consisted in deleting some obsolete options or packages, and  the `\fb` switch-font command defined just after \begin{document}; re-defining it with fontspec and using Latin Modern rather than Computer Modern since the former exists in Opentype format.

Here is the beginning I used to compile:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font
\newfontface\fb{LMRoman10}

\usepackage{parskip, url} % Formatting packages%% xunicode,xltxtra are obsolete
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors usenames,
%% usenames is an obsolete option

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo %can be \usepackage{fullpage}
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I've deleted the `\fp` command. Same Error
_Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex". The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". See the fontspec documentation for further information._

Comment: I  finally found out what's the problem (personally I use WinEdt so it took me some time to understand why it compiled fine with me and not with you…). The reason is that 1) there is no XeLaTeX submenu in the `Tools` menu 2) `Quick Build` (F1 key) has pdflatex as the default engine. So you have to go to `Options -> Configure TeXmaker` and change Quick Build settings in favour of XeLaTeX. Now I can compile even from TeXmaker

Comment: xetex is not a package, but one of the tex engines — unfortunately not easily accessible from within TeXmaker:(