# Quick build button in texmaker = 3 times pdf2latex and view pdf

Tags: compiling

i use texmaker version 5.0.3 and texlive 2019.

i click oft quick button 1 time, 1 time, 1 time and then click pdf view to see pdf.

How can i merge (pdf2latex 3 times and pdf view) and create new Quick Build rule?

Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about texmaker but isn't a "quick build" and running latex three times somewhat contradictory?? After the vast majority of edits you only need to run latex once.

Comment: Just to know. Why 3 times in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a "User Quick Build Command" as follows:

> Open from menu "Options -> Configure Texmaker ->" and click "Quick
>   Build" icon on the left. Choose "User" option and then click "Wizard".

[image]

> Now you can see "Quick Build Command" window. Add command(s) what you
>   want. Then press OK.

[image]

That's it. Now Texmaker compile your file 3 times as `pdflatex` and you can see your document as `pdf`.

Comment: this seems like an answer to me (I don't think the OP should be asking for this but presumably this _is_ the answer on how to do what is asked)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, So I shouldn't have written it as an answer? If so, I can delete my answer.

Comment: No I mean the opposite, it is the answer I don't think you should tell people not to vote for it:-)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Can it stay that way?

Comment: sure it's your post, it can stay however you wish:-)